# What is and what is not compiled into the final app?

Tags: ios, xcode

For example, I have extra `UIViewController`'s in my Storyboard that I am not using and that are not linked to any scenes.

Do these get compiled into the final app and takes up space on the users devices?

Do extra files that are not used get compiled in the final app as well?

Comment: Most certainly. You can open a view controller from a storyboard programmatically even without segues. This is done by strings on runtime and not on compile time. If files are added to the build phases, it's added to the build even if the files are never used.

Comment: Hey @Robert thanks for your comment, I think it can be counted as a correct answer/answered question?